# if-else Rock Paper Scissors Game

Tags: java, if-statement

I can't see why my program terminates. Example is if I stated the user input is rock, it will sometimes state its a tie or nothing happens/terminates. I tried running bits and pieces of it in different class area but still when I input a value it won't output the results I want in the if/else statements.
I know that the computer choice and user input code is correct. I believe it is the if/else that I am messing up. Correct me if I am wrong..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int compVal = (int) (3*Math.random()) +1;
    char compChoice;
    if (compVal == 1) {
        compChoice = 'R';
    } else if (compVal == 2) {
        compChoice = 'P';
    } else {
        compChoice = 'S';
    }
    System.out.println("Rock, Paper, Scissors-Enter a choice R/P/S: ");
    String mine = keyboard.nextLine();
    char myChoice = mine.charAt(0);
    myChoice = Character.toUpperCase(myChoice);
    if (myChoice == (compChoice)) {
        System.out.println("We both chose the same item-try again");
    } else if (myChoice == ('R')) {
        if (compChoice == 'P') {
            System.out.println("I chose Paper and you chose Rock: Paper covers rock, so I win");
        }
    } else if (myChoice == ('R')) {
        if (compChoice == ('S')) {
            System.out.println("I chose Scissors and you choise Rock: Rock breaks Scissors, so you win");
        }
    } else if (myChoice == ('P')) {
        if (compChoice == ('S')) {
            System.out.println("I chose Scissors and you chose Paper: Scissors cuts Paper, so I win");
        }
    } else if (myChoice == ('P')) {
        if (compChoice == ('R')) {
            System.out.println("I chose Rock and you chose Paper: Paper covers Rock, so you win");
        }
    } else if (myChoice == ('S')) {
        if (compChoice == ('P')) {
            System.out.println("I chose Paper and you chose Scissors: Scissors cuts Paper, so you win");
        }
    } else if (myChoice == ('S')) {
        if (compChoice == ('R')) {
            System.out.println("I chose Rock and you chose Scissors: Rock breaks Scissors, so I win");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (myChoice == ('R')) {...} else if (myChoice == ('R'))` So, if it's not `R` but `R`?! Have a good look at your code and try to work out what would happen for different combinations. E.g. `R` and `S` (hint: *nothing*).

Comment: Have you considered using a case statement? It'd simplify your code a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple if/else statements which can never be executed.

Consider this code

```
if (myChoice == ('R')) {
    if (compChoice == 'P') {
        System.out.println("I chose Paper and you chose Rock: Paper covers rock, so I win");
    }
} else if (myChoice == ('R')) { // this will ONLY execute if the previous if statement is false.
```

Every second `if` clause cannot execute because you have already checked for that condition. i.e. the choise cannot be `R` because if it was it would have executed the previous block.  The simplest solution is to delete the duplicates as you don't need them.

```
} else if (myChoice == ('R')) {
    if (compChoice == 'P') {
        System.out.println("I chose Paper and you chose Rock: Paper covers rock, so I win");
    }
    if (compChoice == ('S')) {
        System.out.println("I chose Scissors and you choise Rock: Rock breaks Scissors, so you win");
    }
```

or even

```
} else if (myChoice == 'R') {
    if (compChoice == 'P') 
        System.out.println("I chose Paper and you chose Rock: Paper covers rock, so I win");
    else
        System.out.println("I chose Scissors and you choise Rock: Rock breaks Scissors, so you win");
} else
```

Comment: As a challenge, you can write this using a fraction of the code you have, you can make the main() method half the length, and then make it half the length again . ;)

Comment: I understand now...I think! So I don't have to repeat an "else if" statement due to the fact that the first "if" statement is false correct? Also you stating that I can re create this source code in on what? 10 string lengths?!

Comment: Yes, The repeated if conditions are you problem. You could probably write this in less than 20 lines total.